# What is this (broken) component in the mains side of an amplifier power supply PCB?

Tags: power-supply, identification, components

I'm debugging/repairing a broken [Logitech Z623](https://www.logitech.com/en-au/products/speakers/z623-speaker-system-thx.980-000405.html) 2.1 speaker system that I received in a broken condition (doesn't power on at all.)

I have pulled apart the subwoofer/amplifier unit, and after removing a heat sink, found an exploded component inside the 240V (mains) side of the power supply circuitry.

[image: Magic smoke came out here]

Both of the 2A 250V fuses were blown. I have managed to de-solder the component, which looks a little like a capacitor to me, but its PCB footprint has a symbol I'm not familiar with - please see picture. It looks like two diodes with tails facing each other.

[image: Mystery circuit symbol]

Its PCB silkscreen label is either `Z1` or `TH2` (not sure which label belongs to it.) Physically speaking, it's quite close to the 240V mains input, next to a small transformer and some inductors and large diodes and the main capacitor.

Can you help me identify this component?

[image: Mystery component]

The component body is partially destroyed, but I can see a backward `RU` manufacturer logo that I've seen before on other components, as well as the code `V743` and the number `2`.

Comment: Now because this was blown, along with the fuse(s), expect more damage elsewhere.  There are probably one or more MOSFET(s), ensure none of those are shorted.  There also should be rectifier diode(s) (perhaps ultra-fast variety) that may also have failed.  When ready to test, wire an incandescent light bulb in series to the power plug.  If it lights and goes out, it should work.  If it stays on, something else is still wrong.

Comment: Thank you @rdtsc for the detailed advice! Do you mean I should wire an incandescent household light bulb (e.g. a 40W one) to the input terminals, and then plug the amplifier power cord in, and then see if the light ignites or goes out? I.e. I don't need to try turning the amplifier board on with it's power switch?

Comment: The idea of the incandescent light is to use it as a powerful resistor between power outlet and device. If the device has a short circuit, the bulb will receive all the power and light up, if the device is at least not dangerously damaged, the bulb will quick fade out when the capacitor(s) are charged. You can connect it instead of a fuse. This is the non spectacular version of a first test with nothing exploding.

Comment: Just wanted to share that I got a replacement varistor in place and 2 new fuses and now the speakers work like a charm :) No other components were damaged. Thanks all for the assistance!

Comment: It seems that a large voltage spike must have entered the unit, causing the MOV to fail and popping the fuses.  This is a good thing; the MOV prevented any further damage.

Comment: BTW: The mentioned UR (written backwards) is not a manufacturer logo. It is an Underwriter Laboratories (UL) quality mark called "UL Recognized". UL is an independent safety certification organisation. Generally safety relevant components may have such a mark. You can find a good article about it here: https://forum.digikey.com/t/understanding-ul-when-is-it-applicable/7223

Comment: Even my Logitech Z623 has broken the same component. Could you please confirm that, after replacing this V7431U. Power supply is working well ?

Comment: Hi @SashiKumara B M - Yep. After replacing this component and both fuses, the unit works perfectly. It is sitting on my desk as my main speaker system for my keyboard to this day.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The manufacturer logo is "Matsushita". It is one of their "V" series varistors.
Looking trough their [product catalogue](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AWA0000/AWA0000COL22.pdf), only the "ERZV07D431" can be a match, with marking "V7431U".

Answer (score 11):

You are looking at a varistor. It's an overvoltage protection for your circuit.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor

To identify a replacement, you should choose one that is around 20V above your peak input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

It was a varistor. Choose one rated for your voltage and similar in diameter to the blown component.

Comment: Above the rated voltage!